# object factory for overloaded functions

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, factory

Usually, an object factory creates instances of classes by calling

```
auto world = ObjectFactory::instance()->create("MatrixTransform");
auto cube1 = ObjectFactory::instance()->create("Cube");
auto sphere = ObjectFactory::instance()->create("Sphere");
```

which uses a map of registered functions with no parameters, such as this one where the class `Node`is the base class for the classes `MatrixTransform`, `Cube` and `Sphere`:

```
// Map of registered factory functions
std::map<std::string, std::function<Node *(void)>> functionRegistry;
```

Now, I would like to register overloaded constructors taking a limited number of parameters (one or 2), such as `MatrixTransform(std::string objectName)` or `MatrixTransform(std::string objectName, glm::mat4 matrixTransform)`, so I can call not only

```
auto world = ObjectFactory::instance()->create("MatrixTransform");
```

but also

```
auto world = ObjectFactory::instance()->create("MatrixTransform", "world");
```

and even

```
auto world = ObjectFactory::instance()->create("MatrixTransform", "world", "glm::mat4())");
```

I know it is possible to store in a map functions having different signatures, meaning functions that have different parameters and/or return types, but how to register functions that have not only different signatures but also the same name, such as the overloaded constructors here above, given that the key in a map must be unique and thus can not be repeated? Could post the whole object factory code if needed. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure this is not getting a bit over-engineered? Is there *really* an advantage to just creating the objects directly, without a factory? I don't see, in your example, how the factory beats a simple `auto world = new MatrixTransform(glm::mat4())`. I'd just consider using `std::unique_ptr<Node>` instead of `Node*`.

Comment: @Christian Hackl I have a large number of classes sharing the same base class with particular instances needing to be created at runtime, so I started by looking into the object factory pattern. And, sure,  will eventually use `std::unique_ptr<Node>` instead of `Node*`.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought of 2 possible solutions.

I could create 3 maps rather than one: one for the functions with no parameters, a second one for the functions with one parameter and a third one for the functions with 2 parameters. This way, I'll have 3 maps, each with unique map entries of functions having identical signatures!

An even simpler solution would be to keep the initial map and continue to create objects with the generic constructor but then use the setters to set their name and matrix transform parameters.

Hey, they really say you gotta ask a question to find the answer! Dream in code.

Comment: Upvoted for recommending boring low-tech solutions that likely work well enough :)

Comment: @Christian Hackl Ha, ha, ha, thanks, you made me smile. Hey, anyone up to throw in some more excitement with a high-tech solution, say some template functions with variable numbers of arguments? ;-)))

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a map for that, if you accept to use an enum class:

```
#include<utility>
#include<string>

enum class Type { MatrixTransform, Cube, Sphere };

template<Type>
struct tag {};

struct Factory {
    template<Type T, typename... A>
    static auto create(A&&... args) {
        return create(tag<T>{}, std::forward<A>(args)...);
    }

private:
    static auto create(tag<Type::MatrixTransform>) {}
    static auto create(tag<Type::MatrixTransform>, std::string) {}
    static auto create(tag<Type::Cube>) {}
    static auto create(tag<Type::Sphere>) {}
};

int main() {
    Factory::create<Type::MatrixTransform>();
    Factory::create<Type::MatrixTransform>("foo");
}
```

Overloading, templates and tag dispatching do the job here.

---

Note: the example requires C++14, but it's a matter of using the right return types instead of `auto` and it works also with C++11.

Comment: Wanted to try maps first. Find interesting the variable arguments template you are using, will definitely give it a try. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @LastBlow Maps have fixed types. You want to use different functions definition as values. It is not possible, unless you end up using functors. In this case, you are simply adding an useless layer on top of the solution based on overloading.